# Why is this inequality true in this linear regression problem?

Tags: proof-explanation, machine-learning, linear-regression

From Understanding Machine Learning:  Theory and Algorithms:

How was the inequality in the red box below derived?

For reference in this learning problem, $L_{D_i}(w) \equiv \Bbb E_{D_i} \space l(w, (x,y))$.

---

[image]